# Building a Model to distinguish between elementary particles from their tracks

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I have a set of variables - positions x1,y1 and time t1 for a specific particle (kaon). Each one of these variables is stored in a separate 1-D histogram. And I have another set of variables positions x2, y2 and time t2 for another particle (pion).

What I want is build a model for a hypothesis test. So if I get a set of experimental data for an unknown particle and I want to test it to figure out if this particle is a pion or a kaon.

Any hints how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are asking is for us to devise some way of distinguishing between particles based on their tracks eg in a Cloud or Bubble Chamber. There are ways of doing this but it requires more information than you are providing. Also, it is not clear what your data consists of because you say each variable is stored in a histogram. If the (x,y,t) data has been separated then the tracks of the particles cannot be reconstructed.

Comment: @sammygerbil yes !! ok thanks alot , what if i constructed a 3d histogram and normalize it knowing The number of bins N , can I start from there??

Comment: The point I am making is that creating a histogram throws away the essential information you need about the track of the particle. It makes no sense to do so. What you need to do (I think) is to calculate some quality of the track (eg radius of curvature, or average speed, or deceleration) and then make a histogram out of that. Your starting point should be to identify some connection between particle properties (eg charge/mass ratio) and properties of the track (eg curvature etc). Otherwise why do you expect your 2 histograms to be different?

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you very much . I guess I was totally lost, can you direct me to something (subject or  book) to have more information about how to do that ? thank you again I apologize if the question was a bit dumb

Comment: The actual question you are asking seems to be: "Given 3 histograms x,y,t of data for a particular particle, is this data more likely to come from a kaon  or a pion?" This is purely a question of statistics with no physics involved at all, and is out of place on Physics SE. From a physics point of view this question seems pointless, because there is no obvious reason why the histograms for kaons and pions should be different.

Comment: Discussion is not permitted in comments like this.  So I have opened a [ChatRoom to discuss your question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43456/maryams-particle-physics-project). I need more information about your problem before I can direct you to a suitable resource.

Comment: I can't use the Chatroom I have to have at least 20 repution to do so :(

Comment: Oh, sorry. Where you are getting your data from? Is this a project for school?

Comment: yes it's a school project. I have 3 root files with ttree of x ,y, t, N( number of bins). and 2 of these are know particles ( kaon and Pion) the third I should figure out if it's more likely to be a pion or a kaon.

Comment: Is it a physics project or maths? Sounds like maths (statistics) to me.

Comment: it's a physics project but it does depend heavily in statistics. I guess i should research more in statistics instead. thanks for your help!

Comment: I recommend that you discuss first with your teacher. I cannot see where physics comes into this project. As I point out above, you may be able to distinguish which particle it is from the curvature of the track. However, if all the individual combinations of (x,y,t) have been separated and made into histograms, the track of a sample particle cannot be reconstructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of random observation before I look at the problem in front of us. First, `TTree`s can hold many things other than just histograms. Second, the problem would probably be easier if the data was in tuple form. Third, this could be treated as a rather simplified verion of the TPC particle ID problem which means that it is (once again) a current data processing problem in the particle physics world, but we usually have energy deposition as well as position (and timing is sometimes a bit ambiguous).

---

If the data you have really is 1D histograms of individual kinematic variables without energy or momentum information, then the only discriminators that you have are the lifetimes (which differ by roughly a factor of 2 for charged pions versus charged kaons) and possibly the range (if you can assume that you are getting range information from the position data).

The problem is complicated by time dilation, and the difficulty of extracting some kind of speed and range from the rather limited data you say that you have.

Once you do that the issue has been reduced to one of statistics, though it may still be non-trivial.